# Reading in values from a tab delimited .txt file

Tags: java.util.scanner

I am attempting to read in values from a tab delimited text file and store them into ArrayLists.  The issue is that some values such as ethnicity and gang may contain multiple strings separated by a single space.  Is there a way to make it so that I may read in all strings until the next tab?  Thank you in advance.

```
while (file.hasNext()) // creates while loop using scanner, in that will
                            // store values in arraylist until it runs out
                            // of values
    {
        // stores values from tab delimited file in specified variable each
        // time the while loop is run
        serial = file.next();
        last = file.next();
        middle = file.next();
        first = file.next();
        soc = file.next();
        birth = file.next();
        ethnicity = file.next();
        height = file.next();
        weight = file.next();
        gang = file.next();
        reason = file.next();
        dateIn = file.next();
        dateOut = file.next();
        parole = file.next();
        cell = file.next();

        // stores values from variables above in the defined array list
        serialList.add(i, serial);
        lastList.add(i, last);
        middleList.add(i, middle);
        firstList.add(i, first);
        socList.add(i, soc);
        birthList.add(i, birth);
        ethnicityList.add(i, ethnicity);
        heightList.add(i, height);
        weightList.add(i, weight);
        gangList.add(i, gang);
        reasonList.add(i, reason);
        dateInList.add(i, dateIn);
        dateOutList.add(i, dateOut);
        paroleList.add(i, parole);
        cellList.add(i, cell);
        i++; // increases value each time loop runs
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file is also line-separated. You should read the file line by line.

```
fis = new FileInputStream("the_file_name");
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     values = line.split("\t");
     serial = values[0];
     last = values[1];

     ...
 }
```

If you want to get an array of all the space-separated values, call `values[6].split(" ");`

Answer (score 0):

The `next` method has the option of taking a string as an argument. The String is a pattern you want to get so you want something like the following

```
String s = file.next("[\\S ]+");
```

Which says grab me anything that is a group of non white space or a space.